# C++ How to iterate over a vector defined as a super class, but call sub class methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, stdvector

I have a Java background and I am trying to understand polymorphism in C++. Specifically, how to iterate over a series of subclasses in a std vector defined by their super class, in order to call a specific method. What I would like to do is have the subclasses override the super class method that will be called. However, I am not sure how to do that in C++.

Here is some code to help with celerity:

```
    class Tile {
    public:
            virtual void drawTile();
    }

    void Tile::drawTile() {} // not sure if this is needed?

    class Tile_Grass : public Tile {
    public:
            void drawTile();
    }

    void Tile_Grass::drawTile() { ... do stuff  ... }
```

What I want to do is:

```
    using namespace std;
    for (vector<Tile>::iterator itr = tileVector.begin(); itr != tileVector.end(); ++itr) {
            itr->drawTile(); // draws Tile_Grass, or any other sub class of Tile, but NOT Tile
    }
```

Right now the for loop only calls "Tile::drawTile()", but I would like to have it call "Tile_Grass::drawTile()", or another subclass of Tile that is in the "tileVector" vector. What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You'll want a vector of `Tile*`, or, better yet, `std::unique_ptr<Tile>`;

Answer (score 3):

You should declare and populate your tileVector with pointers to Tile, not the copy of a Tile object.

Here is a complete Visual Studio 2012 sample project:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Tile {
public:
       virtual void drawTile();
};

void Tile::drawTile() {} 

class Tile_Grass : public Tile  {
public:
       void drawTile();
};

void Tile_Grass::drawTile() {  std::cout << "Drawing Tile Grass" << std::endl;  }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> TileVector;

    TileVector vec;

    // add a few Tile_Grass objects
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Tile>(new Tile_Grass()));
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Tile>(new Tile_Grass()));
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Tile>(new Tile_Grass()));

    for (auto itr = vec.begin(); itr != vec.end(); ++itr) {
        (*itr)->drawTile(); // draws Tile_Grass, or any other sub class of Tile, but NOT Tile
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will output **Drawing Tile Grass** 3 times.

If, instead, you define your vector to contain an instance of the base class Tile, the objects stored in the vector will be **spliced**, even if they are originally created as derived Tile_Grass objects:

```
typedef std::vector<Tile> TileValueVector;

TileValueVector vecv;

// add a few Tile_Grass objects
vecv.push_back(Tile_Grass());
vecv.push_back(Tile_Grass());
vecv.push_back(Tile_Grass());

for (auto itr = vecv.begin(); itr != vecv.end(); ++itr)
    itr->drawTile(); // draws Tile
```

This will print **Drawing Tile** 3 times, assuming:

```
void Tile::drawTile() { std::cout << "Drawing Tile" << std::endl; }
```

What happens in splicing is that only the base object part of the Tile_Grass gets gets copied into vector elements, since you declared that you want the vector containing instances of that base object.